# Ansible wait for initializing host before doing tasks in playbook

Tags: ansible

In my host, it needs time (about 20s) to initialize CLI session,... before doing cli

[image: CLI init]

I'm trying to do command by playbook ansible:

```
---
- name: Run show sub command
  hosts: em
  gather_facts: no
  remote_user: duypn



  tasks:
   - name: wait for SSH to respond on all hosts
     local_action: wait_for host=em port=22 delay=60 state=started

   - name: run show sub command
     raw: show sub id=xxxxx;display=term-type
```

After 10 mins, ansible gives me output which is not the result of show sub command :(

```
...
["CLI Session initializing..", "Autocompleter initializing..", "CLI>This session has been IDLE for too long.", 
...
```

I'm glad to hear your suggestion. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a copy-paste solution for you but one thing I learned is to put a sleep after ssh is 'up' to allow the machine to finish it's work. This might give you a nudge in the right direction.

```
- name: Wait for SSH to come up
  local_action: wait_for
                host={{ item.public_ip }}
                port=22
                state=started
  with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"

- name: waiting for a few seconds to let the machine start
  pause:
    seconds: 20
```

Comment: Tks for your solution. I've tried that but the same result. I just wonder if each playbook make a ssh connection or each task make a ssh connection ?

Comment: That depends on how you configure it. By default the ssh-connection will be reused unless you specify otherwise with `ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=no` in ansible.cfg. That will start a new ssh connection every time (and make Ansible much slower).

Comment: I'm glad to hear your answer. So what is the particular configure to make only one ssh connection on each playbook?

Comment: I'm not sure it will only create one connection for each playbook, but you can enable pipelining as described in the documentation here http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_configuration.html#pipelining

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same problem and this is how I solved it:

```
  ---

  - name:               "Get instances info"
      ec2_instance_facts:
          aws_access_key:   "{{ aws_access_key }}"
          aws_secret_key:   "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
          region:           "{{ aws_region }}"
          filters:
            vpc-id :         "{{ vpc_id }}"
            private-ip-address: "{{ ansible_ssh_host }}"
      delegate_to:         localhost
      register:            my_ec2


    - name:                "Waiting for {{ hostname }} to response"
      wait_for:
        host:              "{{ item.public_ip_address }}"
        state:             "{{ state }}"
        sleep:             1
        port:              22
      delegate_to:         localhost
      with_items:
           - "{{ my_ec2.instances }}"
```

That is the playbook named `aws_ec2_status`.

The playbook I ran looks like this:

```
---
# Create an ec2 instance in aws

- hosts:                nodes
  gather_facts:         false
  serial:               1
  vars:
    state:              "present"
  roles:
   - aws_create_ec2


- hosts:                nodes
  gather_facts:         no
  vars:
    state:              "started"
  roles:
    - aws_ec2_status
```

The reason I split the create and check to two different playbooks is because I want the playbook to create instances and not wait for one to be ready before creating the other.
But if the second instance is depended on the first one so you should combine them.

FYI Let me know if you want to see my `aws_create_ec2` playbook.